# Get data from sqlite database using qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I want to get data from sqlite database, i use this code it's work only for small row but when try something big like 300000 its not working
the code:

```
  QString serVal = "searchItem";
        QSqlQuery qry;

            qry.exec("select * from myTable");

            while (qry.next()) { 
                 if(serVal == qry.value("myCol1").toString())
                 {
                     qDebug () << qry.value("myCol2").toString();
                     qDebug () << qry.value("myCol5").toString();
                     qDebug () << qry.value("myCol8").toString();
                     break;

                 }
            }
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not a useful error-description. also you should use *select ... from ... limit NNNN* if you expect such a large query result.

Comment: the problem is the program stop loading and exit but if use for small data it load it normally, can you please explain select ... from ... limit NNNN how to use it.

Comment: qry.exec("select * from myTable where serVal = 'searchItem' "); would probably be a better query.  It would cut down on the matching records.

Comment: Also try adding `qry.setForwardOnly(true);` before executing your query. It may [make a difference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#setForwardOnly).

Comment: @TrebuchetMS thanks its work

Answer (score 0):

Use QSqlQueryModel instead of QSqlQuery like this:

```
QSqlQueryModel queryModel;
queryModel->setQuery("select * from myTable");

while (queryModel.canFetchMore())
            queryModel.fetchMore();

for (int i = 0; i < queryModel.rowCount(); i++)
{
 // Your data
}
```

Comment: what is the equivalent to this: if(serVal == qry.value("myCol1").toString())

Comment: @ZoroAllam  queryModel.record(i).field(1).value().toString(),